# Ember.js and Dates - showing as one day earlier than actual

Tags: date, ember.js

This has been giving me trouble for a long time now, and I wouldn't think this would be so hard. I have a model with some dates, and date data coming from the API like so:

```
{
  ...
  tollgate1: '2016-04-15',
  tollgate2: '2017-01-01',
  projectClose: '2016-10-21',
}
```

I created a format-date helper (which uses moment.js) to format the dates in view mode, like so:
[image: Viewing dates]

And that's shows it correctly. However, when I switch to edit mode, the input elements are still referencing the same values, but now they all go one day earlier!
[image: Editing dates]

This has been maddening for some time. I've thought it might be due to a like of time zone information in the data, but since I can't change the data that's fed to my app, how can I get it to just display the date in the data, regardless of timezone? For example, with the Tollgate 1 date, I would want it to show April 15 no matter where the user is in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so as with many things, this isn't an Ember thing so much as just a JavaScript thing. It's *really* hard learning both at once!

Since my dates coming down from the API don't have a time zone, they're assumed to be GMT, and so my EST timezone of -4 hours makes it show as the day before. Apparently moment.js has some built-in handling so that's why the format-date helper works fine.

What I did to solve is to just add computed properties on my model for each date, and create a new Date object by pulling out the parts from the input date, like so:

```
function convertDateToUtc(d) {
  if(d) {
    return new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate());
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

export default DS.Model.extend({
...
  tollgate1Date: Ember.computed('tollgate1', function() {
    return convertDateToUtc(this.get('tollgate1'));
  })
});
```